# How to generate document output from text files in TFS

Tags: tfs, msbuild, workflow

We store various design documents within TFS in multimarkdown format. We also have an EXE process that can run to take those MMD files and generate PDF's from them - but just by getting the files from a local folder.
What we'd like to do is to have a process run "on-checkin", just as if you'd run an automatic build on checkin (i.e., ultimately calling msbuild to compile an application) but in our case we'd like it to be able to get a list of the checked in files and to process and generate an output of them. The result doesn't need to be in TFS because they're a build output, not the source.
I'm sure this should be somehow possible by taking the same approach as must be taken by the workflow for a "normal" build.
Has anybody done anything like this or can point me in a suitable direction please ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `exec` task in MSBuild to invoke the exe and "build" your output. Create a file called something like `buildDocs.proj` and check it in to TFS possibly in a folder under the things you want to build. Use the MSbuild below as a guide.

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <Target Name="Build">
        <Exec Command='"My.exe" -My Paramiters' />

        <ItemGroup>
            <CopyItems Include="[path to output]\*.*" />
        </ItemGroup>

        <Copy SourceFiles="@(CopyItems)" DestinationFolder="$(OutDir)\SomeDir" />
     </Target>
</Project>
```

The trick will be in identifying the various paths involved.

Use the default template to build the proj, just as you would a c# project. If you need to pass in additional Parameters to MSBuild you can do this from within the advanced section of the build definition process tab.